# EF Core Property change + Events + Business logic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, event-handling

I have read the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) on Events but can't seem to understand what I would consider to be the basics of an event.

1. How to set up an event for a specific property such that if that property is changed X will happen (changed is defined as in successfully saved to the db).
2. How/where to define what X should entail.

My specific goal is to setup an event such that everytime the property *PhoneNumber* changes on a User the service method *HandlePhoneNumberChangeAsync* should be be called. Imagine that the property *PhoneNumber* currently can be changed from many many sources.

Pseudo code

```
public class User
{
   private string _phoneNumber;
   public string PhoneNumber
      {
        get => _phoneNumber;
        set
        {
            if (_phoneNumber == value) return;
            _phoneNumber = value;

            PhoneNumberChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
   }
  
   public event EventHandler PhoneNumberChanged;
}

public UserHandler 
{
    public Task HandlePhoneNumberChangeAsync(User user) {
       var x = await _db.GetUser(u => u.Id == user.Id)
       // business logic
    }

}
```

Is Events totally wrong for this goal? Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1 like this? `userIntance.PhoneNumberChanged += (s, e) => {  /*s is object but can be casted to User ... e is EventArgs.Empty*/ };`

Comment: @Selvin I don't understand, why would I need userInstance? Do you mean I have to trigger the event everytime? I thought that the point of events was that the event would trigger automatically, i.e. that you only needed to set up an event and that HandlePhoneNumberChangeAsync would be called everytime  PhoneNumber changed.

Comment: It seems like you are not getting some basics... User class has nothing with how the data is stored in database... It is just representation of table ON CLIENT side... I'm pretty sure that EF has no built-in way to observe changes on database itself (it is aware because it checks if data was changed before saving but nothing more)

Answer (score 0):

Your **User** class is ok. Now, You must implement the **PhoneNumberChanged** event, and in your main method, You must add this implementation to your User class instance:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        User myUser = new User();
        myUser.PhoneNumberChanged += HandlePhoneNumberChanged;
        
        myUser.PhoneNumber = "123";
        myUser.PhoneNumber = "456";
    }

    static async void HandlePhoneNumberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Phone number has changed");
        User user = sender as User;
        var x = await _db.GetUser(u => u.Id == user.Id);
        // business logic
    }
```

Comment: I was hoping you did not have to use the line `myUser.PhoneNumberChanged += HandlePhoneNumberChanged`. Otherwise I could just directly call the method `HandlePhoneNumberChangeAsync` everywhere the phonenumber property is changed...